# OpenAM Authentication - logout

Tags: java, authentication, logout, openam

I'm beginner with OpenAM, I'm working on an existing project.

I use this documentation to improve our authentication service:
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/10.0.0/dev-guide/index/chap-authentication.html

The login works fine, I receive my token Id and add it in the cookies. I stay connected when I browse restricted web pages.

Now I want to do a clean logout.
When you read the documentation about logout, they propose this code:

```
    protected void logout(AuthContext lc)
    throws AuthLoginException {
    lc.logout();
    System.out.println("Logged Out!!");
}
```

But in my program, I do not have the login AuthContext anymore.

Is there a way to get or create an AuthContext associated with my user ? This call is it necessary ? (actually, We modify the cookies to be rejected by OpenAM)

Thank you.

Answer:

```
SSOToken ssoToken = SSOTokenManager.getInstance().createSSOToken(tokenId);
AuthContext authContext = new AuthContext(ssoToken);
authContext.logout();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I think you should be able to create a new AuthContext by having access to the session token, by using [this](http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/openam/javadocs/internal/com/sun/identity/authentication/AuthContext.html#AuthContext(com.iplanet.sso.SSOToken)) constructor.

Secondly it is not necessary to use the ClientSDK to perform authentication remotely, you could also just use the [REST APIs](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/dev-guide/index.html#rest-api-auth), which probably would be a bit more lightweight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I can logout: See the original post for the answer.    
Concerning the ClientSDK, I join an existing project and the SDK is everywhere, I need more experience to think about replacing it.

Comment: Note that you could have also just use destroyToken on SSOTokenManager, see  http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/openam/javadocs/internal/com/iplanet/sso/SSOTokenManager.html#destroyToken(com.iplanet.sso.SSOToken)